# Rank Nullity Theorem for Infinite dimensional vector spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Rank nullity theorem can be extended for infinite dimensional vector space.Can someone help me to complete my proof.I think this idea will work.

Rank Nullity Theorem states that if $T$ is a linear transformation from $V \rightarrow W$, then ,

$ dim(V) = dim(ker T) + dim(range T)$

If $U$ is a subspace of $V$ then,

$ dim(V) = dim(V/U) +dim(U)$

The Rank Nullity theorem can also be stated in terms of exact sequences if ,
$0 \rightarrow U \rightarrow V \rightarrow W \rightarrow 0$ is a short exact sequences of vector space over the field $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$,  then we have ,
$dim(V) = dim(U)+dim(W)$.

This can be generalized to infinite exact sequences because any finite exact sequence of vectors spaces terminating with $0$ at both ends can be considered as an infinite exact sequence in which all remaining terms are 0.
This generalization is possible if,

$...V_{n-2} \rightarrow V_{n-1} \rightarrow V_{n} \rightarrow V_{n+1} \rightarrow V_{n+2}...$
is an exact sequence of vector space over $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$,then we have ,

$\sum_{n- even} dim(V_{n}) = \sum_{n-odd}  dim(V_{n})$

Thanks in Advance

Comment: What do you mean by $\dim(V\setminus U)$ ? $0\not\in V\setminus U$
so this isn't a vector space

Comment: $V/U$ is not a vector space.But,still that equation holds right.Am I right ?

Comment: What is a dimension of something that is not a vector space ?

Comment: If you can write down the vector space as direct sum of $V/U$ + $U$, then this is true right ?

Comment: No, not to mention that again that a direct sum in this context is defined to be a direct sum of vector spaces, the definition requires that the zero vector is in the intersection, here the intersection is an empty set.

Comment: Maybe consider looking at the proof for the finite case, it doesn't use $V\setminus U$ either

Comment: Can you help me to clear my mistake

Comment: Why can't we write it like the direct sum ?